# How to jBox from JS?

Tags: jbox

(*This is embarrassing, I should not be asking this...but I just don't see the problem...*)

As part of a JS-Fn, I would like to give the user immediate feedback by opening a jBox-Tooltip that is attached to the control user is dealing with. But the control tip does not open - what am I doing wrong? I have simpified stepwise by removing params and finally even this does not do.

```
var x=new jBox('Tooltip',{content:"Press Escape again to clear the input-field!"});      
x.open();
```

I started with

```
var x = new jBox('Tooltip',{
    content:"Press Escape again to clear the input-field!",
    attach: "#ipExpr",
    onInit: function() { this.open(); }
});
```

**NB**: I've chedcked that `$("#ipExpr").length==1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that attaching the jBox to an element and opening it when its being initialised seems to be the problem. Can you describe what kind of behavior your looking for in detail? For example, if you like to open the jBox right away on the element with id #idExpr, you could do it like this: [jsfiddle.net/pbrrah37](http://jsfiddle.net/pbrrah37)

```
  var x = new jBox('Tooltip',{
      content:"Press Escape again to clear the input-field!",
      onInit: function() { this.open({target: $('#ipExpr')}); }
  });
```

Comment: Thank you - that did exactly what I wanted! (I must admit I did not intend to use "attacch", you correctly changed that to "target") :-)